# How to apply d/dt to solve for equations of motion (Applying Lagrangian to Vibrations)

Tags: derivatives, euler-lagrange-equation

In my engineering vibrations course, I am encountering derivatives that are partial as well as total. I am a little rusty and am having a really hard time grasping why the differentiation with respect to time is done differently in some scenarios.

**Here is an example from my book:**

[image]

I circled the two confusing terms in red and green. Why is the red term using chain rule while the green term simply takes a derivative with respect to x_dot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is
$$d\dot{x}/dt=\ddot{x}$$
but
$$d(\dot{x}^2)/dt=2\dot{x}\,d\dot{x}/dt=2\dot{x}\ddot{x}$$